# What happens to all the shards of broken glass that get recycled?

Tags: recycling, glass

I searched for recycling glass and there are no results.

https://www.chestercountyswa.org/DocumentCenter/View/1646/New-Mixed-Paper-Guidelines?bidId=

What happens with the broken glass in the recycling? Do little bits of glass escape and potentially cut people? Do magnets prevents all of the danger? Not all recyclable are magnetic. It was not allowable to recycle glass down a chute in an apartment building.

Comment: all glass for recycling is crushed and a magnet is used to remove most of the metall before the glass is melted,any waste metall will float or sink when the glass is melted this slag can be easily removed https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glass_recycling

Comment: While you have to make sure to throw away the glass separately, first.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question; to recycle glass it doesn't matter if it's broken or not. As user trond hansen commented everything is melted anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glass is broken up into cullet. When recycled it ends up being used to make the very products it was originally made from. Glass is infinitely recycle-ble it doesn't lose it's propensity for quality for every recycling cycle. You can recycle it 1000 times it's still good glass. Glass (besides lead crystal) is inert and non-toxic thus disposing of glass in landfills or open poses no real environmental hazard. Artificial sand (made of glass crushed to particulate size) is being used in construction and beach nourishment projects all over.

Comment: In warmer climates littering glass can start wild fires.